# Biometrics prompt (face authentication) when camera access is blocked (Android 12 - Pixel)

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-12

**Android 12** came up with a new Privacy Settings to disable access to the Camera and Mic sensors, which is referred as [Toggles](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/explaining-access#toggles) in the docs.

As it is mentioned in the docs:

> the system reminds the user that the device-wide toggle is turned off

However, it seems that it only reminds the user when requesting the Camera permission and not when trying to authenticate the user using biometrics (face authentication on Pixel phones, which guess what!? It uses the camera). [I'm using AndroidX biometrics library]

Is there any way to find out if the Camera access has been blocked by the user without requesting any permission?

I guess the note in the docs didn't take into account that the app might use face authentication:

> Note: The toggles mentioned in this section shouldn't require changes to your app's logic, as long as you follow privacy best practices.

*Notes:*

- *You can't register a new face in Settings when camera access is blocked. The Settings app does not show any error, just a blank camera feed*
- *I am using Pixel 4 (Android 12)*
- *The feature 'Join Wi-Fi by scanning a QR code' does not work and neither shows a feedback to the user if Camera access is blocked (Pixel 5)*

Answer (score 3):

So, I also looking for a solution - a have a biometric library and few reports appear in DM with the same problem - FaceUnlock doesn't work on Pixel 4 when the camera 'muted'

For now, still now fix, but maybe my research can help someone.

**1.**  I checked the new API for PrivacyToggle's.
Android 12 introduces a new `SensorPrivacyManager` with `supportsSensorToggle()` method - it returns TRUE in case of device able to 'mute' camera or mic.

```
val sensorPrivacyManager = applicationContext
        .getSystemService(SensorPrivacyManager::class.java)
        as SensorPrivacyManager
val supportsMicrophoneToggle = sensorPrivacyManager
        .supportsSensorToggle(Sensors.MICROPHONE)
val supportsCameraToggle = sensorPrivacyManager
        .supportsSensorToggle(Sensors.CAMERA)
```

If you look into SensorPrivacyManager, you can find that it provides some more useful methods, so I develop the next code:

```
fun isCameraAccessible(): Boolean {
        return !checkIsPrivacyToggled(SensorPrivacyManager.Sensors.CAMERA)
    }

    @SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
    private fun checkIsPrivacyToggled(sensor: Int): Boolean {
        val sensorPrivacyManager: SensorPrivacyManager =
            appContext.getSystemService(SensorPrivacyManager::class.java)
        if (sensorPrivacyManager.supportsSensorToggle(sensor)) {

            val userHandleField = UserHandle::class.java.getDeclaredField("USER_CURRENT")

            userHandleField.isAccessible = true

                    val userHandle = userHandleField.get(null) as Int

                    val m = SensorPrivacyManager::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
                        "isSensorPrivacyEnabled",
                        Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
                        Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
                    )

                    m.isAccessible = true

                    return m.invoke(
                        sensorPrivacyManager,
                        sensor,
                        userHandle
                    ) as Boolean

        }
        return false
    }
```

Unfortunately, the service rejects this call due to SecurityException - missing `android.permission.OBSERVE_SENSOR_PRIVACY`, even if we declare it in Manifest.
At least on emulator.

**2.**  We can try to identify a new "sensor-in-use" indicator

```
fun checkForIndicator(){
findViewById<View>(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT)?.let {
                it.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, windowInsets ->
                    val indicatorBounds = windowInsets.privacyIndicatorBounds
                     if(indicatorBounds !=null){
                         Toast.makeText(view.context, "Camera-in-use detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                     }
                    // change your UI to avoid overlapping
                    windowInsets
                }
            }
}
```

I didn't test this code (no real device), but as for me - it's not very useful, because we can check the camera indicator only **AFTER** we start Biometric Auth flow, when I need to understand is camera accessible **BEFORE** Biometric Auth started.

**3.**  Because of PrivicyToogle related to QuickSettings, I decide that perhaps exists a way how Tiles determinate current Privacy Toggle state.
But this API use a very interesting solution - it does not use `Settings.Global` or `Settings.Security` section, instead, all preferences saved in `"system/sensor_privacy.xml"` and not accessible for 3rd party apps.

See [SensorPrivacyService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/SensorPrivacyService.java)

I believe that exists a way how to find that Camera is blocked, but seems like some deeper research required

**UPDATED 28/10/2021**

So after some digging in AOSP sources, I found that **APP_OP_CAMERA** permission reflects the "blocking" state.

Just call `if(SensorPrivacyCheck.isCameraBlocked()){ return }` - this call also notify the system to show the "Unblock" dialog

[Example](https://github.com/Salat-Cx65/AdvancedBiometricPromptCompat/blob/c5ede763b45f1bd6b003cb26c5d2ddda43e8a748/biometric/src/main/java/dev/skomlach/biometric/compat/BiometricPromptCompat.kt#L275)

Solution:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY)
object SensorPrivacyCheck {
    fun isMicrophoneBlocked(): Boolean {
        return Utils.isAtLeastS && checkIsPrivacyToggled(SensorPrivacyManager.Sensors.MICROPHONE)
    }

    fun isCameraBlocked(): Boolean {
        return Utils.isAtLeastS && checkIsPrivacyToggled(SensorPrivacyManager.Sensors.CAMERA)
    }

    @SuppressLint("PrivateApi", "BlockedPrivateApi")
    private fun checkIsPrivacyToggled(sensor: Int): Boolean {
        val sensorPrivacyManager: SensorPrivacyManager =
            AndroidContext.appContext.getSystemService(SensorPrivacyManager::class.java)
        if (sensorPrivacyManager.supportsSensorToggle(sensor)) {
            try {
                val permissionToOp: String =
                    AppOpCompatConstants.getAppOpFromPermission(
                        if (sensor == SensorPrivacyManager.Sensors.CAMERA)
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA else Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                    ) ?: return false

                val noteOp: Int = try {
                    AppOpsManagerCompat.noteOpNoThrow(
                        AndroidContext.appContext,
                        permissionToOp,
                        Process.myUid(),
                        AndroidContext.appContext.packageName
                    )
                } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                        PermissionUtils.appOpPermissionsCheckMiui(
                            permissionToOp,
                            Process.myUid(),
                            AndroidContext.appContext.packageName
                        ) else AppOpsManagerCompat.MODE_IGNORED
                }
                return noteOp != AppOpsManagerCompat.MODE_ALLOWED
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the first approach but I assumed I would get some some sort of exception, and indeed it does throw SecurityException.

Comment: So I have found solution. See post update